pfSense и ACME Package
Установил pfSense на VPS. Пытаюсь настроить HTTPS через ACME Package. При нажатии кнопки "Issue/Renew" ошибка:

[Sat Aug 10 21:25:06 MSK 2024] Invalid status, <адрес_pfSense>:Verify error detail:<IP_pfSense>: Invalid response from http://<адрес_pfSense>/.well-known/acme-challenge/82aqer3l0-IEmAjgnYk8yeSqk2N5Hzc0ULaT6lpQSnc: 404

